# How to check that current type (object of Type) has needed interface (or parent type)

Tags: c#, .net, types

I've a some type (object of `Type`). Need to check that this type has interface IList. 
How I can do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have an object `type` with the type `System.Type` (what I gathered from the OP),

```
Type type = ...;
typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(type)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Type.GetInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterface.aspx) method.

```
if (object.GetType().GetInterface("IList") != null)
{
    // object implements IList
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to use [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

So from your example:

```
Type customListType = new YourCustomListType().GetType();

if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(customListType))
{
    //Will be true if "YourCustomListType : IList"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is` to check:

```
MyType obj = new MyType();
if (obj is IList)
{
  // obj implements IList
}
```